# How to display the values of a model that contains a HashMap of objects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a hashmap as follows:

```
HashMap<String, Object> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

The data in it looks like this:

```
{CompanyName=null, CompanyId=null}
```

I would like to iterate over this and display values from it in my presentation layer.
I add it to my model as follows:public String

```
showPage(Map model)
{
        HashMap<String, Object> myHashMap =  new HashMap<String, Object>();

        model.put("company", myHashMap);

        return "page";
}
```

My JSP

```
<h1>${companyName}</h1>

<fieldset>
    <p>
        <form:label path="companyName" cssErrorClass="form-error">Issuer Name</form:label>
    </p>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Next" class="round blue ic-right-arrow" />
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'companyName' of bean class [java.util.HashMap]: Bean property 'companyName' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Comment: Seems like a premature submit?

Answer (score 0):

try like below it might work

```
${company["CompanyName"]}
```